# Translating text using string resources in Android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I am making an android app just to try out using string resources to automatically change the text to the Norwegian language. This by saving the default english texts strings in a strings.xml file, and the norwegian translation in a different strings.xml file in a different values-folder. The emulator is set to the Norwegian language. In theory the app should display Norwegian text. Unfortunately when I run the app, only the default english text shows. What is wrong here? Why does the text still appear in english?

First the translated norwegian strings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">TesterActivityForLoop</string>
<string name="txtView1">Trykk knapp nr. \"1\" tre ganger</string>
<string name="txtView2_1">Bra, du trykte rett knapp</string>
<string name="txtView2_2">Gal knapp</string>
<string name="txtView2_3">"Gal knapp"</string>
<string name="action_settings">Instillinger</string>
</resources>
```

Then the default english strings.xml-file:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">TesterActivityForLoop</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="txtView1">Push button \"1\" three times</string>
<string name="txtView2_1">Good, you pushed the right button</string>
<string name="txtView2_2">Wrong button</string>
<string name="txtView2_3">"Wrong button "</string>
</resources>
```

Then an overview of the project:

[image: Project]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `values-no` to `values-nb_NO` . That's Norway's correct Android **locale**.

Comment: Thank you for the reply which led me in the right direction. Changing to "values-nb_NO" gave me this error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/runeasheim/AndroidStudioProjects/TesterActivityForLoop/app/src/main/res/values-nb_NO: Error: Invalid resource directory name However, when I changed it to "values-nb" it worked. Thank you!

Comment: The region needs to be preceded with 'r', so it would be: values-nb_rNO

Answer (score 4):

For Norwegian you have the following possibilities, so you should add them all.

```
nb   - Norwegian Bokmål
nn   - Norwegian Nynorsk
no   - Norwegian
```

In addition you also have the more specific ones which end with _rNO, but I believe that it is sufficient with these three.

```
nb_rNO   - Norwegian Bokmål
nn_rNO   - Norwegian Nynorsk
no_rNO   - Norwegian
nb_rSJ   - Norwegian Svalbard and Jan Mayen
```

A good resource for getting the correct locale is to use Android studios new resource directory. 
You can get this by right-clicking on the resource folder and select new resource file. Then you can click on locale.

This will give you a list of available languages.
[image]

Comment: I like this approach. gives a lot more clarification on langugae-region based localization